# Is there a way to share text on facebook messenger without SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Is there a way to share text on facebook messenger without SDK?

I found the following method.

```
-(void)shareAction:(NSString *)str param:(NSString *)strTitle
{
    NSString *title = strTitle;
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:str];

    NSArray *postItems = @[title, url];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                            initWithActivityItems:postItems
                                            applicationActivities:nil];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[];    
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, not just how to select Facebook Messenger among the various apps,

I want to send it directly to Facebook Messenger.

Is there a way without the SDK?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **UIActivityViewController** to share the app using Facebook Messenger. Please check following sample URL which will display the App list which have implemented share extension.

http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-share-things-with-a-uiactivityviewcontroller/

Comment: Please~ I want to send it directly to 'Facebook Messenger' ONLY!
Other apps should not be seen. I hope there is no selection window.